# update weekly fact in oracle without date

Tags: oracle, plsql, aggregate

I am working on a project in which I have to create a table containing only last 7 days aggregated values. The structure of the target table is :

```
customer_id,distinct_products

1, 20
2, 5
3, 0
4, 2
5, 3
```

Now consider the above as values as of today **12-Jan-2016** meaning aggregated based for **(05-JAN-2016 to 12-JAN-2016)**

Now tomorrow when I have to update this table it should contain the values aggregated based upon data from **06-JAN-2016 
to 13-JAN-2016**

Problem is I cannot Re-Aggregate for all the 7 Days again everyday as each day contains Million of Rows.

I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: Why is the millions of rows a problem? Banks do this all the time

Comment: Getting a *distinct* count is going to be tough.  Do you need 100% accuracy?  If not, you can use a one-pass, approximate NDV (number of distinct values) algorithm to create a synopsis (hash) for each day.  Then the new day's data only has to be scanned once and that synopsis can be added to other days.  Oracle does something like this for incremental statistics, and even made some of the functions available in 12c, such as APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT.  That's a huge amount of effort for an estimate though - are you sure you can't recalculate all days every day?

Comment: @edheal I agree with you, however, I have limits on budget and processing power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following steps I found to work quite fast and accurate :

> 1-Process 1 day (day-1 every day) data create an aggregate table `customer_id,date,prod_id` I am calling it Stage_Agg. Everyday add 1 day data and remove 1 day data which is `>Day-7`
>
> 2-Process Stage_Agg to produce a 2nd Aggregate table called Stage_Agg7 this will generate a table `customer_id,distinct_prod_count7`
>
> 3-Update the Fact table and you are Ok

Let me know what you guyz think.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following logic should work

1. For current day take the aggregate
2. Add it to the existing number in the target / aggregate table for current week
3. Divide the result of step 2, by the current day of the week, ranging from 1-7 and update the aggregate table with the result

The aggregate table would then have your "running" average for the week and you would only need to aggregate the current day which is needed anyways.

Hope this logic helps..

Comment: Well Distinct count is important

Comment: I have made a solution will share in a day or two after validation. Thanks for the valuable input all.